# react native detect screen other components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

hi I want to ask question

I have screen1.
here, I want to detect screen1 at other component using react native navigation

for example,

if(isOpenScreen1) {
...
}

is this possible?
I'd appreciate it if you could answer

Comment: what react navigation version you are using?

Comment: Your question lacks clarity and deatils. Provide a full minimal example in form of a full code snippet which reproduces your issue. Then, tell us what exactly is going wrong and what exactly you are trying to achieve.